# What makes Durvasa a monk?

Tags: rishi, durvasa

If the monk Durvasa gets so agitated easily how can he be a monk because monks remain so calm all the time. 
Ex - Buddha, Ramkrishna etc

So, what makes Durvasa a monk?

Comment: Our ideas of Monk is very naive and childish. Shiva is the greatest ascetic. You know Shiva. Their anger is not the same anger of a compulsive human being. They have mastered anger. Every quality of divine man is not the same as that of a reactive human. They would have mastered the quality. A Buddha is not perfect because he is peaceful. He is peaceful because he is perfect. And a perfect being can choose to be in various forms. Avadhutas are an example of this.               

Here is Sadhguru speaking on this great detail https://youtu.be/0M3Wrs5Cn-0

Comment: Very good question. Durvasa was a RISHI .He was definitely not Muni. You could check Wikipedia for his details and also http://mantrashlokas-madhuri.blogspot.com/2011/09/rishi-durvasa.html. His anger is caused by the Tamo-guna of Lord Shiva and it preserves Dharma.